# Replacing Adobe discontinued fonts with similar fonts

Tags: adobe-indesign

adobe discontinued fonts I used extensively in a brochure. how can I replace the fonts without reformatting? I need to match the fonts as closely to original as possible.

Comment: Welcome Therese! I'm unclear what sort of answer you are expecting. Obviously, you would replace the fonts. If you can find the fonts from their original foundry, that may be best. But it also may be costly. Either way, it's most likely going to entail some reworking.

Comment: I don't quite get why Adobe discontinuing a font would impact fonts you already bought. I still have fonts I got in the 90s… no-one is stopping me from continuing to use them, whether they're still for sale or not.

Comment: I have a trifold brochure created in Adobe InDesign. Adobe no longer supports the fonts used in it. I tried substituting Adobe's recommended fonts and formatting is messed up. I hoped to avoid recreating the entire brochure

Comment: Do you mean you do not have the font and so get a missing font message when opening the file in InDesign?